# Why Array.reduce function not called for items pushed into original Array during reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Given the following code:

```
const ports = [null,3001];

function getPort(port)
{ return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  { // setTimeout to simulate getting port from OS
    setTimeout(() =>
    { if(port < 3010)
      { return reject();
      }
      return resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

ports.reduce(async (acc, port, index) =>
{ if(!port)
  { return;
  }

  try
  {
    const avail = await getPort(port);
    return port;
  }
  catch(avail)
  { ports.push(++port);
  }
});
```

Why is the reduce function only called for elements `null` and `3001` and not `3002` even though at the end of the `reduce` call the Array `ports` is equal to `[null, 3001, 3002]`?

Before the last reduce call completes, the original array already has a new element so why is it not called for that element as well?

The aim of the code is to try and find an available port starting at a given number and increment until we find one, or we hit an upper limit.

There are other ways of doing this, but the `reduce` method seemed the most succinct until I hit this dead end.

Comment: `reduce` is not the correct tool if you A) Aren't doing anything with `acc`, and B) Aren't using the return value of `reduce`. The above is best done with a simple loop, not `reduce`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [that's how it's defined](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce):

> **The range of elements processed by `reduce` is set before the first call to `callbackfn`. Elements that are appended to the array after the call to reduce begins will not be visited by `callbackfn`.** If existing elements of the array are changed, their value as passed to `callbackfn` will be the value at the time `reduce` visits them; elements that are deleted after the call to `reduce` begins and before being visited are not visited.

*(my emphasis)*

But separately, because your callback is an `async` function using `await` on `getPort` before pushing the array, the `reduce` call completes before any call to `push` even occurs. `reduce` does its work *synchronously*, even if you hand it an `async` function. `async` functions return *promises* (if you look, `acc` on the second callback will be a promise).

> The aim of the code is to try and find an available port starting at a given number and increment until we find one, or we hit an upper limit.

A simple loop would be...simpler:

```
async function findPort(start, max) {
    for (let port = start; port < max; ++port) {
        try {
            await getPort(port);
            return port;
        } catch (e) {
            // keep looking
        }
    }
    throw new Error(`No available port found starting at ${start} and stopping before ${max}`);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function getPort(port) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // setTimeout to simulate getting port from OS
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (port < 3010) {
                return reject();
            }
            return resolve();
        }, 200);
    });
}

async function findPort(start, max) {
    for (let port = start; port < max; ++port) {
        try {
            await getPort(port);
            return port;
        } catch (e) {
            // keep looking
        }
    }
    throw new Error(`No available port found starting at ${start} and stopping before ${max}`);
}

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log("Trying 3001 through 3020");
        let port = await findPort(3001, 3020);
        console.log(`Got port ${port}`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`Failed: ${e}`);
    }
    try {
        console.log("Trying 3001 through 3009");
        let port = await findPort(3001, 3009);
        console.log(`Got port ${port}`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`Failed: ${e}`);
    }
})();
```

...but I couldn't quite get what the `ports` array was for, so...

Comment: … and that's *before* you add in the async function and the fact `ports.push(++port);` doesn't run until *after* the `reduce` function has finished.

Comment: @Quentin - Indeed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what I was ultimately aiming for was making a change to [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port/blob/master/index.js#L16) to allow the `npm module` to also accept a range (keeping the changes to a minimum so) not modifying the existing `reduce` flow.

Comment: @HaykoKoryun - It would have been useful if you'd included that information (and code) in the question. That function *already* accepts a range: Set `port` to an array of the ports you want it to try, and it will use the first available one. (Notice that that code *does* use the accumulator of the `reduce` and its return value; it's a fairly standard promise sequence idiom.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it does accept a range, however it's inefficient if you need to give it a range of say 200 ports. I wanted to change it so that you could give it a range as a `String` e.g. `'3000 - 3200'` and then dynamically alter the original array.

Comment: @HaykoKoryun - Inefficient how? An array with 200 entries isn't remotely a problem. But if you wanted to get rid of the array, the answer shows you how above. Without an array, you wouldn't use `reduce`.

Comment: Say you wanted ports in the range of `3000` - `4000`. Up front you would need to create an array of 1000 elements using `push`. In the way I wanted to make it work (impossible with reduce now I know), you would only push new ports into the array until you found a match, so most of the time something like `50` push operations as opposed to `1000`.

Comment: @HaykoKoryun - But what purpose does the array serve in that case? Why not just use a simple loop?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't want to change the whole flow of the mentioned module, so wanted to stick to reduce (even though now I know it's impossible)